# Multiple Elasticsearch indexes with a single node

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch as a centralized logging platform . As most examples show I've been logging to multiple indexes time-stamped by day (e.g. `logmessages-2017-04-14`)

However, I only have a single node setup that contains all these daily indexes. Would I be better off just logging to a single `logmessages` index on this single node?

Since I only have a single node I have replicas set to 0 and shards set to 1 for each daily index. I'm indexing about 100,000 documents per month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **"no"**.

A logging use case always has a retention period defined, meaning after some time you don't need those logs anymore and you need to delete them. This is the same with Elasticsearch indices: when the retention period has been reached that log is deleted.

With time based indices, you delete one day's index and that's it. It's much much more preferred to delete entire indices than individual documents from indices.

Comment: I think we should consider documents count also here. As he will be indexing only `100k` docs per `month`, I'd prefer having all of them on one index rather than creating 30 small indices.

Comment: The preferred approach also includes monthly indices ;-).

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes I'm considering monthly if not quarterly or annual indexes now.